# Getting DefaultView through client object model

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I want to load fields of the **default view** for Sharepoint `list` through **client object model** (I am using Silverlight). Here are some relevant things I've found ([on msdn here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee544361.aspx)):

- class `List` has property `DefaultViewUrl` [of type `string`]
- class `List` has method `GetView(Guid)`
- class `List` has property `Views` [of type `ViewCollection`]
- class `ViewCollection` has method `GetById(Guid)`
- class `ViewCollection` has method `GetByTitle(string)`
- class `View` has property `DefaultView` [of type `bool`]

That's everything I was able to find. As you can see there is no direct way of getting DefaultView (there is missing `DefaultViewId` property on `List` or `GetByUrl(string)` method on `ViewCollection`).

Seems to me as the only solution is to iterate through `List.Views` collection and check `DefaultView` property on each `View`. Which is kind of...well, inefficient...

Did I miss something? Anyone see some straigh solition?
Thanks for ideas.

Comment: What are you looking for? The name of the default view so you can display it? I believe by default it will retrieve the fields for the default view as defined by the user.

Comment: AFAIK `List.Fields` contains **all** fields. Class `View` has property `ViewFields` which should contain only subset of all fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try LoadQuery using a LINQ statement

For Example:

```
private IEnumerable<View> viewQuery = null;
public void LoadDefaultView()
{
    using (ClientContext ctx = ClientContext.Current)
    {
        list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("YourList");

        viewQuery = ctx.LoadQuery(list.Views
                   .Include(v => v.Title) // include more lamda statements here to populate View Properties
                   .Where(v => v.DefaultView == true));

        ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync(LoadDefaultViewSuccess, LoadDefaultViewFailure);
    }
}
private void LoadDefaultViewSuccess(object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs args)
{
    // should only be one View in views
    View defaultView = viewQuery.FirstOrDefault();

    // use default.Title here
}
private void LoadDefaultViewFailure(object sender, ClientRequestFailedEventArgs args)
{
    // handle failure here
}
```

MSDN SharePoint 2010 Silverlight COM article here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538971.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What about [`SPList.DefaultView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.defaultview%28v=office.14%29.aspx)? The SPList DefaultView member is an SPView object (not bool)

Comment: I am talking about **Client** Object Model. Not standart Object model of Sharepoint. I am using Silverlight. (I added some mentions to the post to be more clear)

Comment: Gotcha, haven't used the Client Object Model yet, based on the MSDN documentation I'm concluding the same thing you have, no `GetByUrl` method for instantiating a `View` and no method for getting the `DefaultView` from a `List` without iterating over the `Views`.

Comment: Thank you for rechecking the documentation. I leave the question open, just in case someone will come up with something...